# Show/hide div using trigger with specific class to toggle div with same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, loops

I have my `triggers` and `divs` to show/hide in a while loop, instead of using  `div id` which has to unique, i've decided to use `div class` to show/hide a group of content among others.

**what i'm trying to achieve:**

i'm not at all good with javascript, and i've been trying to achieve this for days. Say i have a trigger with `div class="view1-'.$id1.'"` where `$id1=2` and `div class="licom-'.$cc_id.'"` where `$cc_id=2`  to show/hide, is it possible to ensure that my trigger would only show/hide the `div class` with the same id as `2`?.

**JavaScript**

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var showText='View all replies';
var hideText='Hide';
// initialise the visibility check
var is_visible = false;
// append show/hide links 
$('.view1').prev().append();
$(".licom").hide(); 
$(".view1").click(function(){//i need to pass the div class with the variable
// switch visibility
is_visible = !is_visible;
// change the link depending on whether the element is shown or hidden
$(this).html( (!is_visible) ? showText : hideText);
 //i also need to pass the right div class with the right variable, and keep the others hidden
$('.licom').toggle(function() {
$(this).closest('view1').find('.licom').hide();
return false;
 },
function() {
$(this).closest("view1").next(".licom").show();
return false;
 });  
    });          
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**info.php**

```
  <?php
  ...........
   $stmt = $conn->prepare(
  "SELECT *
  FROM comment
  WHERE post_id = :pid
  ");

$stmt->bindParam(":pid", $type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);


$stmt->execute();

while($obj = $stmt->fetch()){
     $username = $obj['user_name'];
      $comment = $obj['comment'];
      $id1 = $obj['id'];
      $userimage = $obj['user_image'];

  echo '<div class="txt">';
  echo '<div class="comment-container">';
  echo '<div class="comment-item">';
    echo '<div class="comment-avatar">';
      echo '<img src="user/user_images/'.$userimage.'" alt="avatar">';
    echo '</div>';
     echo '<div class="comment-post">';
      echo '<span style="font-weight:bold;">'.$username.'&nbsp&nbspsaid....  
     </span>';
      echo '<p style="margin-left:-11px;">'.$comment.'</p>';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="'.$id.'">';

       //trigger to hide/show replies
             echo '<span class="view1-'.$id1.'" style="float:right;margin-top:-15px;">View all replies</span>';
             //

          echo '</div>';

         echo '</div>';

          echo '</div>';  

         echo '</div>'; 
        echo '</div>';

 //Relpy to comment, show only the first row
 $rep = $conn->prepare("SELECT  * FROM reply WHERE comment_id = :comid LIMIT 1");
$rep->bindParam(":pid", $id1, PDO::PARAM_INT);


$rep->execute();

while($obj = $rep->fetch()){
    //...........same output as first without the view all replies trigger......

//Relpy to comment, show from row 2-
$rep = $conn->prepare("SELECT  * FROM reply WHERE comment_id = :comid LIMIT 1,18446744073709551615");
$rep->bindParam(":pid", $id1, PDO::PARAM_INT);


$rep->execute();

while($obj = $rep->fetch()){

$cc_id = $obj['comment_id'];
//div to show/hide
echo '<div class="licom-'.$cc_id.'">';
 //...........same output as first without the view all replies trigger......

}
  }
     }
 ?>
```

how do i re-write my JavaScript so that all div of class `"licom"` are hidden by default, and only the div with the same id as the trigger say `2,3,...` as the case maybe would show/hide onClick.

Comment: Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/qjadyznh/ ?

Comment: @jvv, awesome. it works. post your answer, so i can accept it.

Comment: Just did, glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in the comments on question:

"Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/qjadyznh/ ?"

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($('.'+id).css('display') == 'none')
    {
        $('.'+id).css('display','block');
    }
    else
    {
        $('.'+id).css('display','none');
    }
})
```

Simple example on how to achieve the goal needed.